# Minecraft - creating spigot plugin - testing for op

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm creating minecraft spigot plugin, how can I test if player is op?

For example in

```
if (player.hasPermission("example.permission"){ //do something }
```

I can use .hasPermission.
Is there something like that for checking op?
Does op have all permissions?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, pineapple500! The rest of this comment is not for you but the person who downvoted your question. To the person who downvoted the question: Please don't downvote a new user's first question without explanation. Take the time to explain what you think is wrong with the question to make the new user feel welcome and to teach the person about SO. SO has been sliding downwards for years...help reverse the trend with a little civility and kindness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this query to check if the player is OP.

```
if (player.isOp()) {
//Do the things you wanna do
}
```

Comment: Worth noting that there is API documentation that can usually help to figure out what you can do with different objects: https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/ . But in this specific case you'd have to know about the ServerOperator interface.